# Efficiently obtaining the union of pandas indices

Tags: python, performance, pandas

I have two pandas dataframes `df1` and `df2` and I want their "merged index".

By that I mean the index that is obtained when I do for instance `df1.add(df2, fill_value=0).index` (basically, a union of the row names). This kind of computation (here, `add`) is performed in separate scripts, and I don't want to compute the "merged index" in these scripts, but I would also like to avoid doing these computations when I'm just interested in the "merged index".

**Is there a more "direct" (and hopefully efficient) way of doing this?**

My goal is actually to associate "tags" to index elements. I have several pairs of dataframes. Each pair corresponds to one "tag" and may have overlapping indices. Different pairs correspond do different tags, and they are supposed do have no overlapping indices.

Basically, I'm looking for an efficient implementation of an `associate_tag` function that would work as follows:

`dfA_1`:

```
idA_1    2    0
idA_2    1    0
idA_3    0    2
```

`dfA_2`:

```
idA_1    3    2    1
idA_3    2    6    2
idA_4    4    0    2
```

`merge_A = associate_tag((dfA_1, dfA_2), "A")`:

```
idA_1    A
idA_2    A
idA_3    A
idA_4    A
```

`dfB_1`:

```
idB_1    2    2    1
idB_2    3    0    0
idB_3    3    1    3
```

`dfB_2`:

```
idB_1    0
idB_2    3
idB_4    2
```

`merge_B = associate_tag((dfB_1, dfB_2), "B")`:

```
idB_1    B
idB_2    B
idB_3    B
idB_4    B
```

`total_merge = pd.concat((merge_A, merge_B))`:

```
idA_1    A
idA_2    A
idA_3    A
idA_4    A
idB_1    B
idB_2    B
idB_3    B
idB_4    B
```

I know what tag to associate to the index elements of a given pair of dataframes, and the `associate_tag` function would ideally completely ignore the numbers in the dataframes.

Here is a non-ideal implementation:

```
from functools import reduce
from itertools import repeat

def add_dataframes(df1, df2):
    return df1.add(df2, fill_value=0)

def sum_dataframes(dfs):
    return reduce(add_dataframes, dfs)

def associate_tag(dfs, tag):
    return pd.concat((sum_dataframes(dfs).index, repeat(tag)), axis=1)

def associate_tag(dfs, tag):   
    s = sum_dataframes(dfs)
    return pd.DataFrame(list(zip(s.index, repeat(tag)))).set_index(0)
```

I plan to use this `total_merge` to easily add a "tag" column to dataframes containing a mixture of index elements. For instance, I could have:

`df`:

```
idA_2    5    4    1
idB_1    1    0    0
idB_4    2    1    2
idA_4    2    3    2
```

And I would then use `pd.concat((df, total_merge), join="inner", axis=1)` to add an extra column with the tags:

```
idA_2    5    4    1    A
idB_1    1    0    0    B
idB_4    2    1    2    B
idA_4    2    3    2    A
```

Is there a better way to do this kind of operation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally found out that pandas `Index` object had an `__or__` implementation.

Hopefully the following version of `associate_tag` avoids superfluous operations:

```
from operator import or_ as union
from itertools import repeat
from functools import reduce

def associate_tag(dfs, tag):   
    idx = reduce(union, (df.index for df in dfs))
    return pd.DataFrame(list(zip(idx, repeat(tag)))).set_index(0)
```

Comment: Note: I'm on `pandas==1.5.0` and it still works, but issues a FutureWarning: `Index.__or__ operating as a set operation is deprecated, in the future this will be a logical operation matching Series.__or__.  Use index.union(other) instead.`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment here is an amended solution:

Two parts:
Combining your dataframes, depending on your column names, you could just pd.concat your whole list of dataframes once you've made sure the column names line up. So if:
dfA_1 is:

```
       col1  col2
index            
idA_1     2     0
idA_2     1     0
idA_3     0     2
```

and
dfA_2 is:

```
       col1  col2  col3
index                  
idA_1     3     2     1
idA_3     2     6     2
idA_4     4     0     2
```

then

```
final = pd.concat([dfA_1,dfA_2])

final
       col1  col2  col3
index                  
idA_1     2     0   NaN
idA_2     1     0   NaN
idA_3     0     2   NaN
idA_1     3     2   1.0
idA_3     2     6   2.0
idA_4     4     0   2.0
```

To fill those NaNs with zeros:

```
final.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

Part 2, the tags:
Once you have that creating the tags is as easy as defining a map for the index, you can either write a simple function, hardcode a dict, or use a lambda:

```
final['tag'] = final.index.map(lambda x: x[2])

final
       col1  col2  col3 tag
index                      
idA_1     2     0   0.0   A
idA_2     1     0   0.0   A
idA_3     0     2   0.0   A
idA_1     3     2   1.0   A
idA_3     2     6   2.0   A
idA_4     4     0   2.0   A
```

Comment: I was somehow hoping that pandas had an internal and efficient way to achieve this (I suppose it does it when I add dataframes), so that I would not have to "manually" build the deduped index.

Comment: You could probably simplify the last step of your solution by using the fact that the tag is known: `final["tag"] = "A"`. Besides, in my real case, the tag cannot be inferred simply from the row names anyway.
Do you know if using `concat` is more efficient than using `add` as I did in my "non-ideal implementation"?

Comment: Yeah I just mapped tag to the 3rd character because that would have also given the right B tag in your sample data, but you could create a dict with a discrete mapping or a function depending on what your real ids look like. You can just pass a dict to map too. I don't know for sure concat is more efficient in all use cases but it is simpler implementation using pandas built in functions. You didn't mention speed was a constraint but I'd bet its at least as good and much simpler to debug.

Comment: And in case it wasn't clear concat will work on a list of dataframes and behave as expected so long as the column names align in each one. So no loops needed just pd.concat(dfs). You can eliminate the need for itertools operators and functools which cleans it up nicely.