# Union of a list of indices

Tags: python, pandas

How do I get the union of a list of indices in pandas? I have the following, but is there a more elegant way?

```
import pandas as pd

def union_list_indices( list_of_indices):
    new_index = pd.Index([])
    for index in list_of_indices:
        new_index = new_index.union(index)
    return(new_index)
```

Comment: Are there any requirements on keeping the elements ordered?

Comment: Also posting example indices would be useful.

Answer (score 4):

Referring to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44761846/efficiently-obtaining-the-union-of-pandas-indices), you could do a small modification and try

```
from operator import or_ as union
from functools import reduce
import pandas as pd

df_a = pd.DataFrame.from_items([('A', [1, 2, 3]), ('B', [4, 5, 6])],
                        orient='index', columns=['one', 'two', 'three'])
df_b = pd.DataFrame.from_items([('C', [7, 8, 9]), ('D', [10, 11, 12])],
                        orient='index', columns=['one', 'two', 'three'])
df_c = pd.DataFrame.from_items([('E', [7, 8, 9]), ('F', [10, 11, 12])],
                        orient='index', columns=['one', 'two', 'three'])

def idx_union(mylist):
    idx = reduce(union, (index for index in mylist))
    return idx

bar = idx_union([df_a.index, df_b.index, df_c.index])
```

Not sure if you consider it more elegant, but it's something.